# How to modify CalendarView minTime/maxTime/slotDuration?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, odoo

I need to modify:
SlotDuration to '00:10:00'
minTime to '08:00:00'
maxTime to '22:00:00'
without messing with the original code

from what i've seen i need .js with the changes i want to make and .xml to put it in assets_backend

call_calendar_change.xml

```
<odoo>
<template id="assets_backend name="assets_backend_new" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
<xpath expr="." position="inside">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/anser_ricardo/static/src/js/change_calendar.js"></script>
</xpath>
</template>
</odoo>
```

change_calendar.js

```
odoo.define('anser_ricardo.call_calendar_change', function(require){
"use strict";
var CalendarView = require('web.CalendarView');
CalenderView.include({
minTime: '08:00:00'
maxTime: '22:00:00'
slotDuration: '00:10:00'
})
});
```

but what i have clearly doesn't work, i think the problem is in .js file, can anyone help me? I saw 2/3 people with the same question as me, but no answer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
odoo.define('anser_ricardo', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var CalendarModel = require('web.CalendarModel');

    CalendarModel.include({
        _getFullCalendarOptions: function () {
            var res = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            return _.extend(res, {
                minTime: '08:00:00',
                maxTime: '22:00:00',
                slotDuration: '00:10:00',
            });
        },
    });
});
```